# What is the name of this closure operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

For any relation $R$, let $\overline{R}$ denote its transitive closure, and define the function $\Omega_R:\wp(\operatorname{fld}(R))\to\wp(\operatorname{fld}(R))$ by$$\Omega_R:P\mapsto{P}\;\cup\;\{\;y\in\,\operatorname{fld}(R):\exists{x, z}\in{P}\,[x\overline{R}y\,\wedge\,y\overline{R}z]\;\}$$

**Question:** Given $P\subseteq\operatorname{fld}(R)$, is there a *standard name* for the derived set $\Omega_R(P)$?

In the question title, I called this a "closure" operation because I *think* that $\forall\,P\subseteq\operatorname{fld}(R)\;[\;\Omega_R(\Omega_R(P)) = \Omega_R(P)\;]$.

It reminds me of the definition of the ["convex hull"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a set of points in, say, a Euclidean space.  Here, "in-between-ness" is defined through a relation $R$ (or, if you prefer, through its transitive closure $\overline{R}$), rather than through a convexity condition equation (i.e. $y = tx + (1 - t)z$, for all ${x, z}\in{P}$ and $t\in[0, 1]$).

---

**Notation and terminology:**

- $\operatorname{fld}(R)$ is the smallest set $S$ such that $R\subseteq{S\times{S}}\;.$
- $\wp(X)$ is the powerset of $X$.
- A relation $R$ is said to be *transitive* iff $\forall{x, y, z}\;[\,(xRy\,\wedge\,yRz)\,\to\,xRz\,]\;.$
- If $R$ is a relation, the *transitive closure* $\overline{R}$ of $R$ is the smallest transitive relation that contains $R$.

Comment: I guess ${\rm fld}(R)$ is the set $X$ where the relation $R$ is defined, i.e. $R\subset X\times X$? Or perhaps the smallest such $X$. Please clarify.

Comment: @Berci: I added the missing definitions.